# Flex - Can I retrieve the ByteArray from a FileReference class using Adobe Flash Player 9?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, arrays, filereference, flash-10

I am trying to retrieve the ByteArray from a file selected using the FileReference class so that I can pass this to a Web Service call that I am making to Sharepoint.
Is there any way I can do this using Flash Player 9 without having to upload to a remote server first and then downloading the file to extract the ByteArray?

This is assuming you can't use Adobe Flash Player 10 and the data property from the FileReference class.

Thanks,
Mauricio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.  Flash Player 9 doesn't allow access to the `load()` function and the `data` property that make this possible in FP 10.

You can provide additional POST data in the data field of our URLRequest--depending on your web service this might make direct communication possible.  Or it might allow you to put up a proxy on the server that makes the web service call for you (rather than posting the file and retrieving it).